# If statement not executing. Python

Tags: python, if-statement, calculator

I am still new to programming and I wanted to do a simple calculator in python. However, I could only reach this point of my code:

```
import operator as op
print("Greetings user, welcome to the calculator program.\nWe offer a list of functions:")
print("1. Add\n2. Subtract\n3. Multiply\n4. Divide\n5. Modulus\n6. Check greater number")
while True:
    userInput = input("Please choose what function you would like to use based on their numbers:")
    if userInput.isdigit():
        if int(userInput) in range(1,7):
            str(userInput)
            break
        else:
            print("Number inputted is either below or above the given choices")
            continue
    else:
        print("Incorrect input. Please try again.")
        continue

def add(x,y):
    return op.add(x,y)

def sub(x,y):
    return op.sub(x,y)

def mul(x,y):
    return op.mul(x,y)

def div(x,y):
    return op.truediv(x,y)

def mod(x,y):
    return op.mod(x,y)

def gt(x,y):
    if x == y:
        return "Equal"
    else:
        return op.gt(x,y)

variableA = 0
variableB = 0

while True:
    variableA = input("Enter the first value: ")
    if variableA.isdigit():
        float(variableA)
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect input. Please try again.")
        continue

while True:
    variableB = input("Enter the second value: ")
    if variableB.isdigit():
        float(variableB)
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect input. Please try again.")
        continue
    
if userInput == 1:
    print("You chose to add the two numbers and the result is:")
    print(add(variableA,variableB))
    print("Thank you")
elif userInput == 2:
    print("You chose to subtract with the two numbers and the result is:")
    print(sub(variableA,variableB))
    print("Thank you")
elif userInput == 3:
    print("You chose to multiply the two numbers and the result is:")
    print(mul(variableA,variableB))
    print("Thank you")
elif userInput == 4:
    print("You chose to divide with the two numbers and the result is:")
    print(div(variableA,variableB))
    print("Thank you")
elif userInput == 5:
    print("You chose to find the modulo with the two numbers and the result is:")
    print(mod(variableA,variableB))
    print("Thank you")
elif userInput == 6:
    print("Is the first input greater than the second?")
    if sub(variableA,variableB) == True:
        print(f"{sub(variableA,variableB)}. {variableA} is greater than {variableB}")
    elif sub(variableA,variableB) == False:
        print(f"{sub(variableA,variableB)}. {variableB} is greater than {variableA}")
    else:
        print(f"It is {sub(variableA,variableB)}")
    print("Thank you")
```

Not sure why my if statement is not executing after all the correct inputs from the user. I mostly focused on the error handling part and after everything going well, the if statement is just not executing after that. There could probably be a simple mistake but even I can't understand what's going on here.

Comment: You have six `if` statements.

Comment: Types like `str`, `int`, and `float` don't modify their input. They return (possibly) new values. `userInput` is *always* a `str` value in your code. If you want to convert it to an `int`, you need to say something `userInput = int(userInput)`. Keep in mind that `int` might raise a `ValueError` if it is impossible to turn the input into an `int`, e.g., `int('foo')`.

Comment: @chepner I tried to convert the userInput into int because it won't get verified in the range(). I quite aware of better error handling shenanigans but perhaps I'd like to get raw with my coding first.

Comment: @jarmod I am not sure what you mean by this. I do have 6 ''ifs'' there but those are for triggering each functions conditionally. What do I have to do here?

Comment: The point is, `str(userInput)` is useless for two reasons: `userInput` is *already* a string (calling `int(userInput)` on the previous line didn't change that), and if it *weren't* a string, you aren't saving the newly created string anywhere. Later in your code, `userInput == 1` is false because `userInput` is a string and `'1' != 1`.

Comment: I think you meant `str(userInput)` to be `print(userInput)`.

Comment: Why does `gt` bother checking if the arguments are equal? `x > x` is false, not a special case.

Comment: You said that you're "Not sure why my if statement is not executing". You didn't say which of 6 `if` statements you're referring to. At that point Stack Overflow readers can try and decipher what your question is or move onto another question. I'm suggesting that your question should minimize such ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with type casting. So when you are taking input from the user all the `userInput` is `str` not `int`, so you need to cast it like `userInput = int(userInput)` before doing further calculator operations.
Also, you need to assign the `float` casting to a variable like this `variableA = float(variableA)` and `variableB = float(variableB)` otherwise your add/sub/divide/multiply etc. will not do expected operations.

For example **add** will do concatenation i.e `'2' + '4' = 24` not 2 + 4 = **6.0**

```
import operator as op
print("Greetings user, welcome to the calculator program.\nWe offer a list of functions:")
print("1. Add\n2. Subtract\n3. Multiply\n4. Divide\n5. Modulus\n6. Check greater number")
while True:
    userInput = input("Please choose what function you would like to use based on their numbers:")
    if userInput.isdigit():
        if int(userInput) in range(1,7):
            str(userInput)
            break
        else:
            print("Number inputted is either below or above the given choices")
            continue
    else:
        print("Incorrect input. Please try again.")
        continue

def add(x,y):
    return op.add(x,y)

def sub(x,y):
    return op.sub(x,y)

def mul(x,y):
    return op.mul(x,y)

def div(x,y):
    return op.truediv(x,y)

def mod(x,y):
    return op.mod(x,y)

def gt(x,y):
    if x == y:
        return "Equal"
    else:
        return op.gt(x,y)

variableA = 0
variableB = 0

while True:
    variableA = input("Enter the first value: ")
    if variableA.isdigit():
        variableA = float(variableA)  # <-- fix this line
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect input. Please try again.")
        continue

while True:
    variableB = input("Enter the second value: ")
    if variableB.isdigit():
        variableB = float(variableB)  # <-- fix this line
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect input. Please try again.")
        continue

userInput = int(userInput)  # <-- fix this line
if userInput == 1:
    print("You chose to add the two numbers and the result is:")
    print(add(variableA,variableB))
    print("Thank you")
elif userInput == 2:
    print("You chose to subtract with the two numbers and the result is:")
    print(sub(variableA,variableB))
    print("Thank you")
elif userInput == 3:
    print("You chose to multiply the two numbers and the result is:")
    print(mul(variableA,variableB))
    print("Thank you")
elif userInput == 4:
    print("You chose to divide with the two numbers and the result is:")
    print(div(variableA,variableB))
    print("Thank you")
elif userInput == 5:
    print("You chose to find the modulo with the two numbers and the result is:")
    print(mod(variableA,variableB))
    print("Thank you")
elif userInput == 6:
    print("Is the first input greater than the second?")
    if sub(variableA,variableB) == True:
        print(f"{sub(variableA,variableB)}. {variableA} is greater than {variableB}")
    elif sub(variableA,variableB) == False:
        print(f"{sub(variableA,variableB)}. {variableB} is greater than {variableA}")
    else:
        print(f"It is {sub(variableA,variableB)}")
    print("Thank you")
```

Comment: I see it now, it was really just that simple line I did not include. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the user input is supposed to be an `int`, convert it early and fail fast.

```
while True:
    userInput = input(...)
    try:
        userInput = int(userInput)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not an integer, try again")
        continue
    if userInput in range(1, 7):
        break
    print("Number out of range, try again")
```

and similarly for the operands

```
while True:
    variableA = input("Enter the first value: ")
    try:
        variableA = float(variableA)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("not a float")
```

There's little reason to convert the menu choice to an integer, though. You could simply write

```
while True:
    userInput = input(...)
    if userInput in "123456":  # ... in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
        break
    print("Invalid choice, try again")
```

Comment: I got your point now, I just found out that it is a string value by default! Thank you anyways for teaching me a new thing. Cheers mate!